# Non-created object in parameter

Tags: java

Schildt use the example of the image below to show how a object could be used as parameter.

I have a question concerning this example:

If I want to use a variable as parameter I must declare it first, so why can a object (Test o) be used without being created? How does Java process this?

Sorry if this is a dumb question, I am just trying to understand this in detail instead of just memorizing it.

[image: Copyrights of Herbert Schildt]

Comment: Where is it that you think an object is being used without first having been created?

Comment: Now I undestand it better. Schildt writes: "Although Test is a class type created by the program, it is used in just the same way as Java’s built-in types."  So "Test" is like a built-in type and "o" is like any other variable. Nevertheless, it is a object or, at least, a reference to a future object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are referring to:

```
boolean equalTo(Test o) { ... }
```

The `Test o` in this instance is a parameter definition. When this method is called you must pass in a `Test` object. Prior to doing so you would typically create an instance, although you may pass in `null` if you wish.

Answer (score 1):

When you pass the object as a parameter of a method you don't need to initialize it in the function again. If you do you will create a new object and use the new one instead of the one passed as the parameter. And that is obviously something that you won't most probably want to do.

However the parameter passed can be null so you can add a null checker in the method like this:

```
if(test == null) { return false; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Take the following function as an example:

```
   public class ThisClass{
        void variableAsParameter( int a){
             System.out.println(a);
        }
        public static void main(String args[]){
             ThisClass thisIsAnObject = new ThisClass();
             int variableToBeUsed = 23; 
             thisIsAnObject.variableAsParameter(5);
             thisIsAnObject.variableAsParameter(variableToBeUsed);
        }
   }
```

So in this example, you can see that when you use `variableToBeUsed` as a parameter, you have declared in the main function. Similarly, in the example you posted, the `Test o` actually reference `ob2` and `ob3` from the main function. The parameter and the variable need not have the same name.

Hope this helps.